# Building json document in mysql with multiple tables in hierarchic structure?

Tags: mysql, json

Let's say you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And another like:

```
CREATE TABLE Pets (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    owner_id INT(10) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_owner` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`)
);
```

I would like to be able to run a query that will return:

```
[
    {
       "id": 1,
       "first_name":"bob",
       "pets" : [
              {
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Kitty"
              },
              {
                  "id":4,
                  "name":"Doggy"
              }
        ]
     },
....

]
```

Right now, in our server, we query each table separately, get the results, and then build the structures to return. This seems expensive because it requires multiple calls to the database, as well as making sure that the "WHERE" clause for each of the queries is the same. For instance, the query to get all users with first name Frank, along with all of their pets would be these two:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name
FROM Users u
WHERE u.first_name LIKE 'Frank%'

SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM Pets p
WHERE p.owner_id IN (SELECT u.id FROM Users u u.first_name LIKE 'Frank%')
```

And then we have to save the results in memory to generate the final JSON.

It seems like in mysql 8.x with access to JSON functions, there should be a better way of doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried? You said you know there are JSON functions in MySQL 8.0. Did you read the manual entries that describe these functions? Did you try them out?

Comment: You need in 2 aggregation levels (according to desired output)/ So aggregation in CTE and next one in outer query. `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...))`.

Comment: @BillKarwin - I didn't see any JSON functions that obviously handled hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have written a query to do similar aggregation to JSON format:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
  JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', t.id,
    'name', t.first_name,
    'pets', t.pets
  )
) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT u.id, u.first_name JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'id', p.id,
          ''name', p.name'
        )
      ) AS pets
    FROM Users AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pets AS p ON u.id = p.owner_id 
    WHERE u.first_name LIKE 'Frank%'
    GROUP BY u.id
) AS t;
```

Comment: Note: I have not tested this. But it should give you the principle you can follow.